# Limit student to select only one job offer

Tags: postgresql

I have a database using PostgreSQL, which holds data on students, applications and job offers.

Is there some kind of constraint that will mean a student can only accept one job offer.  So by selecting 'yes' on 'job accepted' attribute, they can no longer do this for any other jobs they may receive?

Comment: Add sample input and Output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly a "constraint".  It is just a column.  In the `Student` table have a column called `AcceptedJobOffer`.  That solves the direct problem.  In addition, you want the following:

```
AcceptedJobOfferId int references JobOffers(JobOfferid)
```

And, then create a unique index on `Applications` for `StudentId, JobOfferId` and include:

```
foreign key (StudentId, AcceptedJobOfferId) references Applications(StudentId, JobOfferId)
```

This ensures that the job offer is a valid job and that it references an application (assuming that an application is a requirement -- 100% of the time -- for acceptance).

Comment: Thanks for the response, i'm still new to this! So the foreign key part i put in the applications table?

Comment: The foreign key goes in `Student` table.  It is another reference that ensures that the accepted job has an applications (if this is a requirement of the data structure).

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you've some kind of job applications table, which has a field called `is_accepted` in it or something to that order. You can add an [exclude constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) on it. [Example here](http://thoughts.davisjeff.com/2011/09/21/database-for-a-zoo-the-problem-and-the-solution/).

An alternative is to add an `accepted_job_id` column (ideally a foreign key) to the students table, as already suggested by Gordon.

Side note: If this is going to be dealing with real data, rather than theoretical data in a database course, you probably do not want to enforce the constraint at all. Sometimes, people want or need multiple jobs, so limiting the system in such a way that they cannot apply to more than one job introduces an artificial limitation which may come back and bite you down the road.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply.  It is for a database course, and it specified in the brief that only one job offer can be accepted by a student.

Comment: @elle_00: Yeah, thought as much. :-) Highlight the potential issue to your professor though, if relevant -- you might get bonus points for anticipating problems that might show up down the road.